# google maps embed api not working on one page not on other

Tags: api, google-maps, embed

I'm using appgini to create some views on tables. One option is to have an Google maps field.

The strange thing I'm seeing is that the iframe generated by this application is looking good, but I'm getting an error like

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or
>   mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.

But when I'm copying the generated iframe  to a separate html file (on same website) it is working fine.

Example of appgini http://www.cs010.cc/Test/Oefeningen2/Oefeningen_view.php

Example (with exact iframe): http://cs010.cc/Test/test.html

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with the http referrers for the Browser API key.
I changed it to *.cs010.cc/* (previously it was http://cs010.cc